# find . and replace with . & newLine & ; in OSX (for total newbie)

Tags: macos, bash, shell, awk

This is what I'm trying to do: Replace all instances of a period with (1) a period, (2) a new line and a (3) semicolon. There are a lot of questions about this that I've been looking at but they assume a lot of programmer knowledge. Here are some things I need to do, that I don't know how to do:

1. Write the path of the txt you want to do a find and replace in correctly.
2. Writing the find and replace command.
3. Choosing what unix tool to use (support for inserting new lines is necessary).
4. Launching it correctly from terminal.
5. How to represent newline in the relevant tool.
6. There's probably something else I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `awk`.

```
awk -F"." -v OFS=".\n;" '{ $1=$1; print $0 }' filename.txt
```

What this does is to view each line of the text file `filename.txt` as a record separated by periods, rebuilding the record with the period, newline, and semicolon as a new field separator.

**Addendum** To capture the output into a file, use a redirection like this:

```
awk -F"." -v OFS=".\n;" '{ $1=$1; print $0 }' filename.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: That was quick! I'm probably doing something very simple wrong: (awk -F"." -v OFS=".\n;" '{ $1=$1; print $0 }' Q/Ø/r/1.txt) gives this output
(awk: can't open file Q/Ø/r/1.txt
 source line number 1) is there something wrong with the syntax? (the folder- and filenames are right for sure)

Comment: Is there some way to use a default directory (desktop?) in which to put the txt? To minimize the "moving parts".

Comment: The awk syntax is fine. Try typing the awk command, then drag the file from the Finder into the Terminal window. That will put in a valid path to your file, which should make clear whether the problem is in how you are giving the file name.

Comment: Yep, I broke it by writing the name of the hd in the filepath. It's working now. Thank you!